# How I can migrate from `MGLConstantStyleValue` to `NSExpression`

Tags: ios, mapbox, mapbox-gl, swift4.1

I'm trying to migrate from `mapbox-sdk-3.7` to `mapbox-sdk-4.0`.

I can't understand how to convert this syntax with `MGLConstantStyleValue` to `NSExpression`.

```
let layer = style.layer(withIdentifier: "milestones") as? MGLSymbolStyleLayer
let styledValues: [String: MGLStyleValue<NSString>] = ...

layer.iconImageName = MGLConstantStyleValue(interpolationMode: .identity,
                    sourceStops: styledValues,
                    attributeName: "imageId")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Identity` interpolation mode uses the value for a feature attribute as a style value. Therefore, a stops dictionary should be unnecessary. In the case you outlined, looked like it used the value for `imageId`.

With `NSExpression`, you may want to try `layer.iconImageName = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "imageId")`

If you would like a stops dictionary to be taken to account, you may want to consider using `MGL_MATCH`, which takes an initial condition, this is followed by possible matches for that key and a corresponding value to assign to the layer property if there is a match. The final argument can be a default style value that is to be used if none of the specified values match.

`layer.iconImageName = NSExpression(format: "MGL_MATCH(imageID, 'imageID1', 'nameForImageID1', 'defaultImageName')")`

You may find these guides helpful:

- [Predicates and Expressions](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/4.0.0/predicates-and-expressions.html)
- [Migrating to Expressions](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/4.0.0/migrating-to-expressions.html)